# Deleting in SQLite Database in Xamarin

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Xamarin and SQLite rookie here! App keeps crashing when trying to remove model from the database I'm trying to implement Sqlite database of this simple model:

```
    public class NoteModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }

}
```

This is my Sqlite Code:

```
    public class SQLiteDataStore
{
    public SQLiteAsyncConnection database;

    public SQLiteDataStore(string dbPath)
    {
        database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
        database.CreateTableAsync<NoteModel>();

    }

    public Task<List<NoteModel>> GetNotesAsync()
    {
        return database.Table<NoteModel>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> SaveNoteAsync(NoteModel model)
    {
        return database.InsertAsync(model);
    }

    public Task<int> DeleteNoteAsync(NoteModel model)
    {
        return database.DeleteAsync<NoteModel>(model);

    }
}
```

Then on my viewmodel:

```
    public static SQLiteDataStore datastore;
    public static SQLiteDataStore DataStore
    {
        get
        {
            if (datastore == null)
            {
                datastore = new SQLiteDataStore(Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "NoteData.db"));
            }
            return datastore;
        }
    }
```

I have no problem Adding items but when I try to delete with this:

```
        private async void OnNoteSelected(NoteModel note)
    {
        await DataStore.DeleteNoteAsync(note);
    }
```

The App crashes as soon as it reaches the line

```
return database.DeleteAsync<NoteModel>(model);
```

The model seem to be alright [image: NoteModel to be deleted]

What am I not getting?

Comment: A crash is an unhandled exception. The exception tells you what happened. You need to actually look at the diagnostic information yourself to try to work out how to fix the issue. If you can't work it out, you need to provide that information to us.

Comment: Have you checked permissions? and does that id match the datatype expected?

Comment: Sorry. The App goes into break mode and I get this : System.NullReferenceException
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The id was created by Sqlite itself with the database.InsertAsync(model) . And this model was displayed with the database.Table<NoteModel>().ToListAsync() function. So that Id was in the database. Also if I seem to have permission to add to the database, is it possible I cant delete?

Comment: What does the stack trace show as the origin of the exception?